# Django 1.9 cannot connect to the MySQL server (blank screen)

Tags: python, mysql, django

I recently upgraded the MySQL version to 5.7.11 and Django to 1.9.2.

When I try commands that needs MySQL connection (`makemigration`, `migrate`, `test`, etc.), I see a blank screen and nothing happens (even after 30mins)

[image: after typing makemigration command]

Any idea what's the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling and install the `python-MySQL` package using `pip` solved the problem.